# Div with horizontal scrollbar contains div with vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I want to create something like this:

[image]

Three and Content will scroll horizontally at the same pace.

The red box around the bottom boxes shows what will be affected by the horizontal scrollbar.  Only the Content div will be affected by the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: post some code for crying out loud!

Comment: Gotta agree with @RachelGallen here.  You're not making a whole lot of sense.  If you want people to help out, you need to put forth the effort in writing out a proper question.

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I'll create a mockup in paint.  I can't post the data or contextual code I'm using, according to my employer.

Comment: @adamdc78 Similar, but not exactly. See changes.

Comment: It's still not clear what the actual problem is. You don't know how to show scrollbars? How to prevent the outer div from having a vertical scrollbar as well? How to give the inner div the correct height? What?